# AngularJS: pushing new data to $scope.myList, top

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is the right to add new content to `$scope.myList = []`, when I want to manipulate the DOM?

I've tried `$scope.myList.push(data);`, which adds the new data at the end, and therefore in the end of the HTML-template inside ng-repeater. I want it at the top.
unshift-function will rearrange the array and update all elements.

New to angular.

EDIT:
Maybe instead the question should be: How should I add new content dynamically into the top of my template?

Comment: I'm intrigued that you say the unshift function will rearrange the array and update all elements. Have you observed this behaviour in practice?

Comment: Well I might be mistaken about it's updating the elements, but something is happening. I have audio elements and they stop playing using unshift, but not with push.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you want to prepend to an array, you will be rearranging the entire array.  If you can dictate the format of the `data`, I suggest you add a `entry_number` or `id` as a field of the `data` and use [angular filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) to place the new items to the top.

Take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/92JnXFimfmfsUUfDVBpk?p=preview).

Comment: I think this is what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: One thing though. In Firefox (not safari or chrome), if the element is inserted above another element, it causes the element under to lose focus (selection, textbox, audio stops etc). This doesn't happen if you append the HTML using jQuery. Any idea why?

Comment: Interesting...  I do not know the answer and sound like a good question to ask.  Why don't you use my plunker and create an example for your next question?