# AngularJS: Access currently listed item in ng-repeat from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have something like this:

```
<div ng-app="test-app" ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul id="contents">
      <li ng-repeat="content in contents">

      </li>

      <button> ng-click="add()" </button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can I do something like this:

```
$scope.add() = function {
 var currentContent = $scope.content;
 //undefined
}
```

I tried different methods but failed, any insight very appreciated!

Comment: Where is $scope.content value assigned.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need a reference to the scope of the last added LI?

Comment: see this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874636/angularjs-pushing-new-data-to-scope-mylist-top)  which points to this plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/92JnXFimfmfsUUfDVBpk?p=preview)

Comment: HTML rule break you cannot put anything inside ul only li is the sole child of ul . You placed an evil button as the direct child of ul. :P
Can you explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: How would you get the `content` when the button (if it was in a valid place anyway) is outside of the scope of your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for wasting everyone's time, turns out I had a misunderstanding on how to approach things, so I refactored the way I send "contents" from the back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside controller

```
...
$scope.add = function(content){
    var currentContent = content;
    //or
    $scope.currentContent = content;
}
...
```

Inside view

```
...
<li ng-repeat='content in contents'>
    <button ng-click='add(content)'></button>
</li>
...
```